# Is there any better way to locate elements for the following HTML code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

For the HTML code below:

```
<div class="advcd_fields form">

other <div> and <p> elements...

   <p><input type="text" class="field" name="" placeholder="Company"></p>
   <p class="submit_btns"> 
      <input type="submit" class="btn" name="" value="Search">
      <input type="submit" class="btn green-btn save_search_btn" name="" value="Save search">
      <input type="submit" class="btn cancel-btn s_close" name="" value="Cancel">
   </p>
</div>
```

I have created the xpath locator for p group elements as

```java
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class=\"advcd_fields form\"]//p//input[@value=\"Search\"]")

@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class=\"advcd_fields form\"]//p//input[@value=\"Save search\"]")

@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class=\"advcd_fields form\"]//p//input[@value=\"Cancel\"]")
```

My questions:

1.
This is working for me. I would like to know if this is the correct way to identify the 3 elements under `p`?

2.
Is there any better/short way to locate these 3 elements?

3.
This is for "Company" element.

```java
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class=\"advcd_fields form\"]//p//input[@placeholder=\"Company\"]")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is working for you that is great news. But there are always multiple ways to do things.

1. Since the `<input>` element is the immediate child of the `<p>` element you don't need the double slash(`//`), single slash(`/`) would suffice.
2. If there are no other `<p>` element with class `submit_btns` then you could discard the `<div>` from the XPath and directly search for the `<p>` element. Like this,

```java
@FindBy(xpath="//p['submit_btns']/input[@value='Search']")
```

3. You could even directly search for the `<input>` element assuming there are no other `<input>` element with the same class or value.

```java
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@value='Search'][@class='btn green-btn save_search_btn']")
```

4. You could use CSS Selectors:

```java
@FindBy(css ="input.btn.green-btn.save_search_btn[value='Search']")
```

You can check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) and search the web for more references and choose the one that is best for you.

Comment: Very nice! This is crisper locator. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and other alternatives. All work.

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML provided, the simplest locators would be CSS selectors like

```
input[value='Search']
input[value='Save search']
input[value='Cancel']
```

Since we can't see the entire page, it may be that there are multiple instances of these buttons on the page. If that's the case, you will need to add some parent-related information to the locator like

```
div.advcd_fields input[value='Search']
div.advcd_fields input[value='Save search']
div.advcd_fields input[value='Cancel']
```

I think with these examples you can see a way to simplify your locators while still keeping them unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='advcd_fields form']//input[@placeholder='Company']")
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='advcd_fields form']/'/input[@value='Cancel']")
```

or with CSS:

```
@FindBy(css="div.advcd_fields.form input[placeholder='Company']")
@FindBy(css="div.advcd_fields.form input[value='Cancel']")
```

Maybe even without the div (depending on the rest of the DOM):

```
@FindBy(css="input[placeholder='Company']")
@FindBy(css="input[value='Cancel']")
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. This is nice too. All locators you specified work (considering DOM of my page).